# How to create responsive graph like stack overflow?

Tags: javascript, graph

I just love stack overflow and keep dreaming about it all nights.

I just want to develop map like https://stackoverflow.com/users/122718/usr?tab=reputation&sort=graph which response based on client's selection of area.

Can any one please guide how to do this?

Comment: You should have a look at [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/). Also you might want to try to use google with any combination of these keywords: chart graph javascript

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/ is the answer. Great docs there too.

Comment: @DeveloperJigarPandya: Do not add signatures to the question. Please read FAQ for more details

Comment: Questions about 'how to do X' should start with what you've researched (and the client-side aspects of Stack Overflow are HTML, CSS and JavaScript, all of which you can look at quite easily), and where you went wrong. Currently you're showing no research effort.

Comment: Is this question "How can I implement this" or "How does SO implement this"?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Highstock chart Api.

Highstock lets you create stock or general timeline charts in pure JavaScrip

Its very similar to Highchart and product of the Highslide.

Column Chart Example : http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/column

Comment: Thanks for edit and answer hardik